# How to do join table by ID as primary key in query -laravel

Tags: laravel, inner-join, join

I want to do a function where filter based on 2 database tables. However, Im not sure how to put the join table in the query. Which means the data will be filtered from two table (user and employee tables) before returning the result to the datatable.

My filter query is

```
public function filterQuery(Request $request){

    $age = $request->age;
    $gender= $request->gender;

    $query = user::query();

    if(!empty($request->age)){
        $query->where('age','>=',$age );
    }

    if(!empty($request->gender)){
        $query->where('gender','<=',$gender);
    }

    $data = $query->get();

    return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
}
```

The table that I want to join in the query is from table employee (column = income and house_ownership) .and the primary key that connect both tables is IC.

Comment: What's relationship between these tables? and age and gender is user's column or employee's column?

Comment: age and gender are from table user. Meanwhile, income and house_ownership are from employee table. They connected by IC as a primary key

Comment: so employ and user are one-to-one relationship? did u build the relationship in both model?

Comment: Like this? return $this->hasOne('App\user'); in employee.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have relationship in both model, you can use `whereHas`:

```php
    if(!empty($request->income) || !empty($request->house_ownership)){
        $query->whereHas('employee', function($q) use ($income, house_ownership) {
             if (!empty($income)) {
                  $q->where('income', $income);
             }
             if (!empty($house_ownership)) {
                  $q->where('house_ownership', $house_ownership);
             }             
        });
    }
...
```

Or you can just use join or leftjoin to filter another table:

```php
public function filterQuery(Request $request){

    $age = $request->age;
    $gender= $request->gender;
    $house_ownership = $request->house_ownership;
    $income= $request->income;

    $query = user::query();
    $query->leftjoin('employee', 'employee.IC', '=', 'user.IC');

    if(!empty($request->age)){
        $query->where('user.age','>=',$age );
    }

    if(!empty($request->gender)){
        $query->where('user.gender','<=',$gender);
    }

    if(!empty($request->income)){
        $query->where('employee.income', $income);
    }
    if(!empty($request->house_ownership)){
        $query->where('employee.house_ownership', $house_ownership);
    }
    $data = $query->select('user.*')->get();

    return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
}
```

Comment: if(!empty($request->income)){
        $query->where('employee.income', $income); does not working (as well as house_ownership) do u know why?

Comment: @wns have you joined the employee table as above code? did it have error message?

Comment: No error on console. when I filter independently by table (like filter only by gender and age , or income and house_ownership, it works). But when I filter age/gender with income/house_ownership, my datatable turns no result (no data is available).

Comment: @wns so are you sure about that there's age/gender with income/house_ownership records exists in database. And `$query->where('employee.income', $income);` means employee income equals to the request income, if you want the range, you can use greater than or less than...

Comment: @wns another thing is laravel's `join` means `innerjoin`, maybe you need `leftjoin` which without employee, the user records will still be displayed. And I have updated my answer to `leftjoin`

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
public function filterQuery(Request $request){

    $age = $request->age;
    $gender= $request->gender;
    if(!empty($request->age)){
       $data = User::where('age','>=',$age)->get();
    }

    if(!empty($request->gender)){
      $data =  User::where('gender','<=',$gender)->get();
    }


    return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Eloquent::when()](https://laraveldaily.com/less-know-way-conditional-queries/) to reduce if-else for Conditional Queries.

```
public function filterQuery(Request $request){

    $query = user::query();
    $query->select('user.*')->join('employee', 'employee.IC', '=', 'user.IC');

    $data = $query
        ->when(request('age') != null , function ($q) {
            return $query->where('user.age','>=',request('age'));
        })
        ->when(request('gender') != null , function ($q) {
            return $query->where('user.gender','<=',request('gender'));
        })
        ->when(request('income') != null , function ($q) {
            return $query->where('employee.income','<=',request('income'));
        })
        ->when(request('house_ownership') != null , function ($q) {
            return $query->where('employee.house_ownership','<=',request('house_ownership'));
        })
    ->get();

    return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
}
```